# Exoplayer - How to play only the current screen visible in FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter with Exoplayer. My main goal is to load the next page, however don't play the video in that page. Right now in my VideoFragment for the viewpager, I am playing the video inside 
`onCreateView`

```
player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build();
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
playerView.setPlayer(player);

addListenerToPlayer();

DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(mContext,
           Util.getUserAgent(mContext, "yourApplicationName"));
Uri uri = Uri.parse(mUrl);

MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
player.prepare(videoSource);
```

How do I setup my exoplayer and adapter so that it only plays the current screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `player.setPlayWhenReady(true);` with `player.setPlayWhenReady(false);` in your initial configuration as this instructs the player instance to play the media as soon as it's ready to be played.

According to the docs on *Player.STATE_READY*:

> The player is able to immediately play from its current position. The
>   player will be playing if getPlayWhenReady() is true, and paused
>   otherwise.

Moreover, you should setup either `PageChangeListener` or `PageChangeCallback` (depending on which version of `ViewPager` you're using) to monitor which page in the `ViewPager` is currently selected and which are not. For the selected page, you can set its corresponding exoplayer instance to play the video with `player.setPlayWhenReady(true)`. It is also a good idea to pause the player in each of your fragment's `onPause(...)` lifecycle method.